# AfxGetInstanceHandle() triggers an assertion failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, mfc

I am using MFC in my C++ program (using Visual Studio 2008). I have to call AfxGetInstanceHandle() at the begining of my program.

This function triggers a break point:

```
AFXWIN_INLINE HINSTANCE AFXAPI AfxGetInstanceHandle()
{ ASSERT(afxCurrentInstanceHandle != NULL);
return afxCurrentInstanceHandle; }
```

The ASSERT statement fails. Is there something special that needs to be done in order to initialize the `afxCurrentInstanceHandle` before we try to access it?

PS: I am using MFC in a shared dll.

**EDIT**

My code is like that:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  CoInitialize(NULL);
  AfxGetInstanceHandle();
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to use the `InstanceHandle` in order to initialize a `CComModule` and then use it to manipulate com object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MFC you shouldn't be providing a main, wmain, _tmain, or WinMain -- MFC provides its own entry point. Put initialisation code in InitInstance of your CWinApp derived class. If you don't have a CWinApp derived class you haven't created the project correctly -- use the Visual Studio Wizards for creating an MFC application.

Comment: So there is no way to access AfxGetInstanceHandle() without having the all CWinApp object ?

Comment: I think I was doing something wrong, and I did not really needed this to use COM object. Thanks.

Comment: Downvote because this is not true. For Window/GUI applications your statement is correct, the project wizzard will create a CWinApp derived class. But when you create a console application with MFC support, then source code with a main (_tmain) function is created and AfxWinInit is called first to set up the MFC.

Answer (score 18):

I made a Console App with MFC and got the Message too. I found the solution, that you need a "prologue" at the beginning of your main (_tmain, etc).

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]) //, char *envp[])
{
    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))  
    {       
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs       
        cerr << _T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed") << endl;       
        return 1;   
    }   
    AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    ...
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I was wondering: shouldn't call to `AfxInitExtensionModule(...)` initialize MFC as well? I still get error when calling `AfxGetInstanceHandle()`. If I add `˙AfxWinInit(...)` error is gone.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```

Before you call:

```
AfxGetInstanceHandle();
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem for me. But the answer of user2528794 works.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you mix unicode/mbcs or debug/release build modes for DLL/application.

Comment: My project and all it's dependencies are being complied using MFC in a shared DLL, with MultiThreaded Debug DLL, and using Multibytes characters. It may be due to something else